# Callback a picture in Cordova custom Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to make a custom plugin for Cordova that will be used for Android. Now, in the src code of the plugin for Android, I have a drawable (icon) which I want to pass it to the Cordova side (The plugin returns a name and its drawable).

So far, the best idea that I could find was to save the image in a temporary folder and give the path back to cordova side. However, since it is never a big picture has anyone any other suggestions to give the drawable as a callback to Javascript side?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Someone contributed to the plugin for Cordova I have wrote, and added this functionality. But the way it was implemented was saving the image to sd card in the plugin and reading it from cordova.

You can check it at https://github.com/jmrezayi2/Applist